# How do I post two instances of the same property from a view to an action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-2

How can I send my data from form, two fields are the same: Station name, but they have different values. How send they via post method to controller. Asp.net mvc2

here what i try:

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm("ViewRes", "Shedule"))
       {%>
    <%= Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Поиск по расписанию:</legend>
        <ul>
        <li>Из<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.StationName) %></li>
        <li>В<%= Html.EditorFor(model1 => model1.StationName) %></li>
        <li>Дата отправления</li>
        </ul>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="OK" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    <% } %>
```

and such controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ViewRes(string a1, string b1)
        {

            DateTime dtm = Convert.ToDateTime("30.11.2011 0:00:00");




            var res = (from d in db.RouteDetail
                       from m in db.RouteDetail

                       lalala
                       where (d.Station == a1
                       &&
                       m.Station == b1)
                     lalalal
                       }).ToList();

            return View(res);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I would approach this is to refactor my model to encompass both of your existing inputs separately.  That way each can be bound accordingly in the action.

```
public class RailwayRoute
{
     public string StartStation { get; set; }
     public string EndStation { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("ViewRes", "Shedule"))
   {%>
<%= Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Поиск по расписанию:</legend>
    <ul>
    <li>Из<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartStation) %></li>
    <li>В<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndStation) %></li>
    <li>Дата отправления</li>
    </ul>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="OK" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
<% } %>
```

Controller/Action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ViewRes(string startStation, string endStation)
{
     ...
}
```

Comment: start and end are good, but in db this is no difference! end or start, only name, and so must be

Comment: @DPS I'm assuming you're using a view-specific model and mapping its properties to your entity model (DB) in your controller.

Comment: i found what i need: <li>Из <%= Html.TextBox("a1") %></li>
        <li>В <%= Html.TextBox("b1") %></li>

Comment: @DPS - but that doesn't tie it to the model properties on display.  I think you'd be better off using a view-specific model with descriptive parameter names that match the model.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on tvanfosson's answer which pretty much sums up, I would try and decouple your data model from your view data.  This is often done by using the MVVMC aproach where VM stands for view model.  In your case you appear to be passing directly the data model to the view which is sometimes not the recommended approach.

So changing tvanfosson's RailwayRoute to a viewModel object I would ensure the controller action maps the data appropiately.  Something like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ViewRes(RailwayRouteViewModel viewModel)
{

   DateTime dtm = Convert.ToDateTime("30.11.2011 0:00:00");


   var res = (from d in db.RouteDetail
              from m in db.RouteDetail
              lalala
              where (d.Station == viewModel.StartStation
                     &&
                     m.Station == viewModel.EndStation)
              lalalal
              select new RailywayRouteViewModel()
              {
                StartStation = d.Station,
                EndStation = m.Station
              }
          }).ToList();

   return View(res);
```

}